# Split a data frame using groupby and merge the subsets into columns

Tags: python, pandas, merge, group-by, outer-join

I have a large `pandas.DataFrame` that looks something like this:

```python
test = pandas.DataFrame({"score": numpy.random.randn(10)})
test["name"] = ["A"] * 3 + ["B"] * 3 + ["C"] * 4
test.index = range(3) + range(3) + range(4)
```

```
id  score       name
0   -0.652909   A
1   0.100885    A
2   0.410907    A
0   0.304012    B
1   -0.198157   B
2   -0.054764   B
0   0.358484    C
1   0.616415    C
2   0.389018    C
3   1.164172    C
```

So the index is non-unique but is unique if I group by the column `name`. I would like to split the data frame into subsections by name and then assemble (by means of an **outer join**) the score columns into one big new data frame and change the column names of the scores to the respective group key. What I have at the moment is:

```python
df = pandas.DataFrame()
for (key, sub) in test.groupby("name"):
    df = df.join(sub["score"], how="outer")
    df.columns.values[-1] = key
```

this yields the expected result:

```
id  A           B           C
0   -0.652909   0.304012    0.358484
1   0.100885    -0.198157   0.616415
2   0.410907    -0.054764   0.389018
3   NaN         NaN         1.164172
```

but seems not very `pandas`-ic. Is there a better way?

**Edit: Based on the answers I ran some simple timings.**

```python
%%timeit
df = pandas.DataFrame()
for (key, sub) in test.groupby("name"):
    df = df.join(sub["score"], how="outer")
    df.columns.values[-1] = key
```

```
100 loops, best of 3: 2.46 ms per loop
```

```python
%%timeit
test.set_index([test.index, "name"]).unstack()
```

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.04 ms per loop
```

```python
%%timeit
test.pivot_table("score", test.index, "name")
```

```
100 loops, best of 3: 2.54 ms per loop
```

So `unstack` seems the method of choice.

Comment: Next time, you should provide a `numpy` seed such that the numbers are identical with your expected result.

Comment: While it doesn't really matter for this question, thank you for the hint @FooBar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you look for is [unstack](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html). In order for `pandas` to know, what to unstack for, we will first create a `MultiIndex` where we add the column as *last* index. `unstack()` will then unstack (by default) based on the last index layer, so we get exactly what you want:

```
In[152]: test = pandas.DataFrame({"score": numpy.random.randn(10)})
test["name"] = ["A"] * 3 + ["B"] * 3 + ["C"] * 4
test.index = range(3) + range(3) + range(4)
In[153]: test
Out[153]: 
      score name
0 -0.208392    A
1 -0.103659    A
2  1.645287    A
0  0.119709    B
1 -0.047639    B
2 -0.479155    B
0 -0.415372    C
1 -1.390416    C
2 -0.384158    C
3 -1.328278    C
In[154]: test.set_index([index, 'name'], inplace=True)
test.unstack()
Out[154]: 
         score                    
name         A         B         C
0    -0.208392  0.119709 -0.415372
1    -0.103659 -0.047639 -1.390416
2     1.645287 -0.479155 -0.384158
3          NaN       NaN -1.328278
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that for my real data frame with 10 M rows this method brought down the processing time from 28 min to 9.5 s, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across a similar problem, which was solved by using a pivot_table

```
    a = """id  score       name
0   -0.652909   A
1   0.100885    A
2   0.410907    A
0   0.304012    B
1   -0.198157   B
2   -0.054764   B
0   0.358484    C
1   0.616415    C
2   0.389018    C
3   1.164172    C"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO(a),sep="\s*")
df = df.pivot_table('score','id','name')


print df
```

Output:

```
name         A         B         C
id                                
0    -0.652909  0.304012  0.358484
1     0.100885 -0.198157  0.616415
2     0.410907 -0.054764  0.389018
3          NaN       NaN  1.164172
```

Comment: It works but `unstack` provides a faster way. Thank you for your answer @ZJS.

Comment: Even though `pivot_table` is not as fast as `unstack`, for my real data frame with 10 M rows this method brought down the processing time from 28 min to a respectable 17 s, thank you :)